# Keyboard shortcut to switch monitor a window is on kali linux

Tags: kali-linux, accessibility, workflow

In windows I can use WinKey + Shift + Left/Right to move a window between monitors but I can't seem to find an equivalent that works on kali linux.

Answer (score 0):

The Shortcuts to move around windows are not something distro dependent. It is dependent on your window manager / desktop environment that you are using. And usually it can be configured to be your prefered key binding.

For Gnome : https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en

For XFCE : https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfwm4/preferences

And yes. If you are happy with the <kbd>Win</kbd>-key (called "Super" in Linux) + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd> / <kbd>Right</kbd>, the same can be configured from the keyboard shortcuts setting.

Answer (score -1):

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ARROW</kbd> LEFT/RIGHT

Have a nice day :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).